# MySQLコマンド　等しいカラムにおける別のカラム同士の積の総和

Tags: mysql, sql

```
|A|B|C 
|1|1|100 
|1|1|200 
|2|1|300 
|2|4|50 
|2|1|100 
|3|1|500
```

MySQLのあるテーブルにA,B,Cというカラムがあり、 上記のような値だとします。

Aの値が等しい行の中で、各行のBとCの積を、すべて足した値が、500以上であるAの値を、重複を避け抽出したいのですが、 どのようなコマンドになるでしょうか？

(例) 
Aが1のとき、`1*100+1*200=300` 
Aが2のとき、`1*300+4*50+1*100=600` 
Aが3のとき、`1*500=500` 
よって、2と3を取得する。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/26518

Answer (score 1):

何のひねりもありませんが、質問通りなら

```
SELECT A
FROM T
GROUP BY A
HAVING 500 <= SUM(B * C);
```